# Deugging In WPF spec. Datagrid

Tags: wpf, debugging, datagrid

I was wandering if someone can tell me how to debug WPF, in my particular case I need to work why my column isn't sorting this is what I have done so far (and I believe its all correct but it still isn't sorting):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSheet}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=FullName}" SortMemberPath="FullName" CanUserSort="True"  />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Can someones please tell how I could debug this, I can click the column header (direction arrows appear) but it doesn't sort :/ im using VS2010 and I have set the Binding Property in the Debug options to all and everything seems to be in order so I am not to sure what else to check :/
Thanks All :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-_- i really wished WPF had better debugging methods, I worked out my problem. it ended up being the type of Collection Model I used.